# Emacs: what is the shortcut key to clear buffer?

Tags: emacs

Like, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (select all) followed by delete?

Comment: A related (common) problem: to clear the mini-buffer using the `esc` key, set this in your init: `(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`C-x h + del` key clears the buffer

*Note:* This requires `transient-mark-mode` to be enabled (which it is by default).

Comment: This (or `M-x erase-buffer`) does not add the contents of the buffer to the kill ring, but `C-x h C-w` does, and `C-x h C-w` also works when transient mark mode is not enabled.

Answer (score 87):

How about using:

```
M-x erase-buffer
```

Which you could bind to whatever you want.

Comment: I have this in my .emacs:  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <deletechar>") 'erase-buffer)`

Comment: For new users, when `M-x erase buffer` is invoked for the first time you will receive a prompt explaining that it has been disabled but you can enable it . If unsure about exactly what this command does, I recommend running it with the `SPACE` option the first time to see what happens.

Answer (score 33):

Select all in Emacs is:

```
C-x h
```

(technically, that's mark-whole-buffer) and kill-region (to kill the marked region, which is now the entire buffer) is:

```
C-w
```

If you want to delete the region without copying it to the kill-ring, you can use

```
M-x delete-region
```

instead. If you do this alot, you'll want to bind delete-region to a key/key combo.

Comment: The difference between this solution and M-x erase-buffer, is that this solution copies the deleted text into the kill-ring. That can be very annoying if one wants to delete a large file as copying a ton of text to the kill ring can be slow. This behavior is even more annoying if one is a user of browse-kill-ring.el

Answer (score 6):

These macros build on the answers given above. To start using them paste them into your .emacs then restart emacs or (while in the .emacs buffer) type M-x eval-buffer.

```
(defun clear-buffer ()
  "clear whole buffer add contents to the kill ring"
  (interactive)
  (kill-region (point-min) (point-max))
  )

(defun clear-buffer-permenantly ()
  "clear whole buffer, contents is not added to the kill ring"
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
  )
```

Comment: `erase-buffer` will clear the buffer regardless of narrowing.  That may or may not be more desirable.

Comment: `erase-buffer` does not add the contents of the buffer to the kill ring however.

Answer (score 5):

Old folks might like to call it hk rather than clear-buffer-permanently,
and assign it to the nostalgic key sequence like so:

```
(define-key esc-map "\^[hk" 'hk)
```

That's the pre-Gnu TECO EMACS command to clear the buffer
(ESC ESC wHole Kill).

Answer (score 4):

Go to the begin of the buffer, go to the end (both set the mark), then cut:

```
M-< M-> C-w
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut, but you can define one...
Follow [this link](http://lazymalloc.blogspot.com/2010/10/emacs-clear-current-buffer.html) to get a macro for clearing a buffer.