# How to copy/select a whole file or buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

Is there any command to select the whole file contents in Emacs?

For example, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> selects whole contents of a file in Notepad, Notepad++, etc.

I can select whole contents using the mouse, but it's inconvenient for large files. I found the basic Emacs commands [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/emacs.html) and [here](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/emacs.html), but could not find what I am looking for.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886745/emacs-what-is-the-shortcut-key-to-clear-buffer/4887184#4887184

Answer (score 95, accepted):

<kbd>C-x h</kbd> will select the entire buffer.

You can search for help within Emacs using the built-in help system.

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> will look for help for specific functions.  In this case, you could have searched for `whole-buffer` to find `mark-whole-buffer`.

Other help commands of interest would be:

- <kbd>C-h m</kbd> to show available commands for the current modes
- <kbd>C-h v</kbd> for help related to variables
- <kbd>C-h k</kbd> to find which functions keys are bound to
- <kbd>C-h w</kbd> to see which key bindings are defined for a given function
- <kbd>C-h ?</kbd> to see which other options are available.

Note that <kbd>C-x h</kbd> will only highlight all the text.  To actually copy the selected text, you must use <kbd>C-w</kbd> for cut (`kill-region`) or <kbd>M-w</kbd> for copy (`kill-ring-save`).

Comment: I tried C-x h but it's not working. It puts the cursor in the beginning of the file and says mark set. But if I try to paste then it does not paste the file contents.

Comment: You probably don't have transient-mark-mode enabled.  Do M-x tranient-mark-mode.  This will show your selected region.  Once you do C-x h, make sure you are copying with C-w.

Comment: Thanks. It's working after I did M-x transient-mark-mode. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Sajib Mahmood: Note that `C-x h` should still work regardless of that mode; you just won't *see* the marked region. So `C-x h M-w` should always copy the buffer's contents. Also, `transient-mark-mode` is enabled by default, so you may want to figure out why it's disabled in your config.

Comment: You are right, @phils. C-x h and then M-w copies the content. Thanks. Without the transient mode it was not showing that it has selected the whole file. I'll look into my configuration.

Comment: @phils, transient-mark-mode is enabled by default from GNU Emacs 23 and onwards. I was using GNU Emacs 21.4.1. May be that's why it was not enabled by default.

Comment: Good point. Also, 21.4 is nine years old. Updating would be well worth considering.

Comment: I made a binding for that: (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-a") 'mark-whole-buffer)

Comment: When I type `C-x h` I only get a right help file `Key translations Starting With C-x:` and not the mark all in the text. What do I do wrong? As a workaround, I had to mark everything with the mouse now.

Answer (score 0):

I use CUA, so I didn't like `mark-whole-buffer` because it doesn't use a temporary region.

After much messing about, I finally achieved this using a keyboard macro saved to a function:

- Define a macro which selects the whole buffer
- Run `kmacro-name-last-macro` to name the macro
- Use `insert-kbd-macro` to script it out
- Now you can copy it into your config & map it to a key, like `C-a`

Answer (score 0):

Copying and selecting are related, but distinct, actions. A file and a buffer are also related, but distinct.

To *copy* a *buffer*, consider using [jac.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/jac). It handles both the "copying" and dealing with modes.